# Trigger event when clicking to the Combobox JavaFX

Tags: javafx, combobox

I have a Combobox with empty elements. I would like to load the content for this comboxbox only when I click to it. I have tried to call *`setOnAction`* but did not success:

```
mycomboBox.setOnAction((e) -> {
      myLoadfunction();
});
```

Can anyone give me a tip how can I do this? Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
comboBox.setOnShowing(event -> myLoadFunction());
```

or:

```
comboBox.setOnMouseClicked(event ->  myLoadFunction());
```

Comment: yes that what I am looking for. Thank you very much!